# Does this param need to be returned in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I am going through the heads first js book and encountered a problem.

On the Console it comes out as 7 still when it should be 8? This is in the book so I'm guessing I'm just missing something basic here.

```js
var age = 7;

function addOne(x) {
  x = x + 1;
}

addOne(age);
console.log(age);
```

Comment: 7 is the correct answer... The book is wrong.  Numbers are not passed by reference,.  If you had age as part of an object literal it would work, as the object is passed by reference.

Comment: There are two examples, the other goes:

Comment: When you call `addOne`, `x` gets the same value as `age`, and that’s where their relationship ends. From there, you have two variables, `x = 7` and `age = 7`, then you set `x` to `8`, then the function returns and `x` stops existing. `age` stayed the same the whole time.

Comment: Ah thanks Keith, I think I got a bit ahead of myself here. It probably explains this more clear later on in the book. It made sense to me returning that value but I see now that it was not the case.

Comment: I see, i just console.logged within the function of x and it came out 8. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Simply explained: You don't do anything with age. In your function you add one to 7 which is stored as 8 into x and after the function is processed you print out age which is still 7.

To answer your question: Returning the param x would let you return 8. So

```
   var age = 7;

   function addOne(x) {
    x = x + 1;
    return x;
   }
   console.log(addOne(age));`
```

should work for you.

Comment: Hi @sho , looks like your new.  Welcome to SO.  Just a heads up, you should be able to just amend your original answer, it's less confusing than replying to your own answer.

Comment: Thanks @Keith. Your are totally right. Fixed that.

Comment: Where’s the global variable here?

Comment: @Ryan  If run outside a module, that `var age = 7;` would be the global var.

Comment: @Keith: Ah, true, sorry – I was meaning to ask about `x` (“though using x as a global var…”)

Comment: @Ryan  Oh yeah, didn't spot he mentioned `x`.. :)  I assume he meant to say `age`.. oops.

Comment: @sho Are you not going to fix the answer in reference to the global bit?

Comment: @Deadalus - done.